# how do i write code to click on save > do this automatically next time > click okay in python using selenium webdriver on firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

How do I write code in python using selenium driver to click on save file > do this automaticlly for these files and click on okay as shown in the image? [image]

I'm using pyhon 3.8 and the firefox browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a better approach will be to directly download the file

```
from selenium import webdriver

# To prevent download dialog from opening
ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
ff_profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
ff_profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/xls;text/csv')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("<url>")

browser.find_element_by_id('<file_element_id>').click()
```

above code will download the file to the default location.
if you want to download somewhere else add the following lines:

```
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom downlaod location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '<your_path>')
```